# ASP MVC 4:  снова проблема с подключением

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день!

использую ВС2010, ASP.NET framework 4.5, MVC. Столкнулся с проблемой.  Храню подключение к веб.конфиге:
[image]

Подключение правильное, я его с помощью Linq2class получил. Построил проект. Выбираю меню ПРОЕКТ/Конфигурация ASP/NET, затем выбираю вкладку "Безопасность"...
и тут мне пишет:

[image]

```
Текст ошибки:
Возникла проблема с выбранным хранилищем данных. Ее причиной могут быть неверно указанное имя сервера, неверные учетные данные или отсутствие прав доступа. Проблема также может быть связана с тем, что функция диспетчера ролей отключена. Нажмите кнопку, расположенную ниже, чтобы перейти на страницу, где вы сможете выбрать новое хранилище данных. 

Следующее сообщение может помочь при диагностике проблемы:  Не удается установить соединение с базой данных сервера SQL Server.
```

Данные в подключении правильные впервые столкнулся. 
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Возможно что в SQL Server не выставлены права для пользователя NETWORK SERVICE для управления базой данных. Ну и в пуле приложений на IIS соответственное тоже должно идти выполнение под NETWORK SERVICE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, подключение к SqlServer требует своего пользователя. Заведите пользователя, дайте ему права на эту БД и пропишите данные пользователя в ConnectionString.
Как формировать ConnectionString, можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Переустановка студии решила проблему, и не только эту. Извините за беспокойство и спасибо всем, кто ответил.